# C++ constructor delegation

Tags: c++, c++11

Можно ли в конструкторе, два раза вызвать другой конструктор?

```
class Constructor
{
public:
Constructor()
{
    printf("Default constructor\n");
}

explicit Constructor(int _a) : Constructor("explicit")
{
    printf("Integer constructor\n");
    this->a = _a;
}

Constructor(std::string _str) : str(_str)
{
    printf("string constructor\n");
    Constructor(true);
    Constructor(1, 2);
}

Constructor(bool _flag) : flag(_flag) 
{
    printf("Bool constructor");
}

Constructor(int a, int b)
{
    printf("one more");
}

void Print()
{
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    printf("flag = %d\n", flag);
}
private:
    int a;
    std::string str;
    bool flag = false;
};
int main()
{
    Constructor cons(1);
    cons.Print();
   return 0;
}
```

Ожидаю увидеть в консоли:

> string constructor
>   Bool constructor
>   one more
>   Integer constructor a = 1 flag = 1

А вместо этого:

> Bool constructor Integer contstructor a = 1 flag = 1

Comment: Constructor cons(int(1)); ?

Comment: Дважды вызвать конструктор нельзя. Вызов `Constructor(true); Constructor(1, 2);` в вашем коде - это создания двух анонимных временных переменных, а не вызов конструкторов для текущего экземпляра.

Comment: @magrif а что изменится? ожидаемо, что результат должен быть тот же

Comment: @Chorkov но ведь Constructor(bool) вызывается и инициализирует поле, которое ожидается

Comment: @raviga  Constructor(bool) Вызывается для другого экземпляра объекта. Добавьте отладочный вывод в деструктор этого класса (с печатью this), чтобы стало очевидно.

Comment: @AnT В классе поле `flag` установлено в `false`. Когда вывожу его в консоль, то у меня результат `1`, а не `0`.

Comment: Начиная с [С++11](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Constructor("explicit")
```

> Implicit conversion turns string literal into bool: `const char[9]` to 'bool'

```
Constructor(std:string("explicit")) //так выполняется как вы ожидали
```

Конструкторы вызывать можно, если в контексте этого же объекта хотите создавать другие(!) объекты этого же типа класса, что и происходит в `Constructor(true); Constructor(1, 2);`, где они сразу же удаляются при завершении работы конструктора.

Comment: Аа, понял почему. Получается вызов с первого конструктора сразу делегируется на `bool` конструктор.

Comment: @raviga ога, тут описано почему https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770297/4607234

Comment: А если бы там был не `string`, а другой тип? Можно в одном конструкторе делегировать аргументы на два других или только с одного на один?

Comment: @raviga как я понял, вы ожидаете для этого же объекта вызвать другие конструкторы, чтобы проинициализировать остальные поля?

Comment: скорее, просто интересует или можно с одного конструктора вызвать несколько других (того же класса). К примеру, допустим: `Cons(int i):Cons(another) {}` или это `Cons(int i) { Cons(another); }`, а  можно ли продолжить как-то эту цепочку? `Cons(int i): Cons(another), Cons(second) {}`... что-то типа этого

Comment: @raviga можно, если в контексте этого объекта хотите создавать другие(!) объекты этого же типа класса, что и происходит в Constructor(true);
    Constructor(1, 2);, где они сразу же удаляются при завершении работы конструктора

Answer (score 1):

- Вызвать несколько конструкторов класса из одного конструктора этого класса можно только через многоуровневую делегацию конструкторов.
- Выбор конструктора при делегации делается по обычным правилам разрешения перегрузки (overload resolution). По этим правилам преобразование аргумента `"explicit"` к типу `bool` является более предпочтительным, чем к типу `std::string`. Потому и вызывается конструктор с параметром типа `bool`

  ```
  void foo(bool) {}
  void foo(std::string) {}

  int main()
  {
    foo("Hello World"); // вызывается `foo(bool)`.
  }
  ```